# Remote validation - Generated remote url is wrong

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-5, remote-validation

I am trying to add remote validation for old password in the Account view (ChangePassword section).

I have a viewmodel `Areas/Private/ViewModels/Account/ChangePasswordViewModel.cs` which contains the `OldPassword` field:

```
[Remote("IsPasswordValid", "Account", HttpMethod="Post", ErrorMessage="Wrong password")]
public string OldPassword { get; set; }
```

And a controller `Areas/Private/Controllers/AccountController.cs` which contains the action for the validation:

```
// ...
[Area("Private")]
// ...

public JsonResult IsPasswordValid(string pwd) {
    return Json(true);
}
```

When I run the project and inspect the OldPassword field I notice the following data-val-remote-url:

```
/Private/Account/Index?action=IsPasswordValid&controller=Account
```

which ofcourse doesn't work. I expected to see the following url:

```
/Private/Account/IsValidPassword
```

Am I missing something here?